# Passing variables as NSDict from Viewcontroller to Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a simple registration storyboard asking the user for their name etc. I am collecting the inputted data as UITextfields and want to pass them all to the final viewcontroller where I make it all an array and fire it off to to server. The JSON but is all working fine with test data added.

BaseViewController

```
   struct NewUserStruct {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
}
```

Sending VC

```
let firstNameReg = inputFirstName.text
    let lastNameReg = inputLastName.text

    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destVC = segue.destination as? RegistrationUpdateViewController {
            let newuser = NewUserStruct(firstName: firstNameReg! , lastName: lastNameReg! )
            print(newuser)
            destVC.newuser = newuser
        }        }
```

and the receiving VC

```
var newuser: NewUserStruct?
func createUser(){

guard let user = self.newuser else {
print("User is not set")
return
}

let service = "registration"
let parameters: [String: Any] = ["firstName": user.firstName,
                                 "lastName": user.lastName,
                                 "email": "Johnsmith@test11.com",
                                 "password": "12345678",
                                 "region": "EU",
                                 "bundleId":    Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!,
                                 "appVersion": Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as! String]
```

This compiles but I get a value of nil for the print(newuser) and it prints the guard "User is not set"

This is my whole VC

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class RegistrationNameViewController: BaseViewController {

@IBOutlet var inputFirstName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var inputLastName: UITextField!



override func setup() {

}

override func navbarTitle() -> String {
    return "Name"
}

override func leftNavbarButtonType() -> NavbarButtonType {
    return NavbarButtonType.eNavbarButtonTypeBack
}

override func rightNavbarButtonType() -> NavbarButtonType {
    return NavbarButtonType.eNavbarButtonTypeNext

}

override func navbarViewNextPressed(_ navbarView: NavbarView) {
    let firstNameReg = inputFirstName.text
    let lastNameReg = inputLastName.text
    print(inputFirstName.text!,inputLastName.text!)

    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destVC = segue.destination as? RegistrationUpdateViewController {
            print(destVC)
            let newuser = NewUserStruct(firstName: firstNameReg! , lastName: lastNameReg! )
            print(newuser)
            destVC.newuser = newuser
        }        }
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "NameToEmail", sender: nil)

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Comment: Since you are using Swift, you should use Dictionary, not NSDictionary. Your receiving dictionary seems to be `NameVars` not `Name2Array`. You shouldn't name variables with an upper case letter and you should use a struct to pass the data rather than a dictionary

Comment: I changed the name as I will eventually have more variables coming into the  final viewcontroller. I think I should have a line let let Name2Array : NSDictionary = self.receiveItem and then the let NameVars : NSDictionary = self.receiveItem
Also I will change the caps. Is there a reason to use Structs and not Dictionaries? I dont fully understand the differences. I am using existing code which is why its NSDictionary and not Dictionary. Thanks!

Comment: The trouble with a dictionary is that it is imprecise; you need to know the key values and if you make a simple typing error then things will break. If you use a struct then the compiler will provide autocomplete and it is more defined what the attributes are. NSDictionary is bridged to a swift dictionary

Comment: var sendItem: NSDictionary!
    var receiveItem: NSDictionary!
This is in my BaseViewcontroller. To change this to a Struct requires me to make a blank one right?
Then I can use dot syntax to append the values?

Comment: Also, how are you assigning the value to `receiveItem` ?  Are you using `prepare(for:)` ?

Comment: We havent been... 
  
  struct senddataStruct {
        var parameters = [String]()
    }

Adding this to my BaseViewController, I guess I can append parameters in the individual VC's and then use those values in my final VC?

Comment: Simply defining a property in a superclass won't automatically assign that value between different instances of that class (or subclasses)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a struct so that you have a proper definition of the data you are passing.

```
struct NewUser {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
}
```

Now you can create an instance of this struct and pass it to your destination view controller in `prepare(for segue:)`

```
override func navbarViewNextPressed(_ navbarView: NavbarView) {
    guard let firstName = inputFirstName.text where !firstName.isEmpty
          let lastName = inputLastName.text where !lastName.isEmpty else {
        print("first name and last name are required")
        return
    }

    let newUser = NewUser(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName) 

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "NameToEmail", sender: newUser)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destVC = segue.destination as? RegistrationUpdateViewController {
        print(destVC)
        if let newuser = sender as? NewUser {  
            print(newuser)
            destVC.newuser = newuser
        }
    }
}
```

In your destination view controller:

```
class RegistrationUpdateViewController {
    var user: NewUser?

    func someFunction {
        guard let user = self.user else {
            print("User is not set")
            return
        }

        let service = "registration"
        let parameters: [String: Any] = ["firstName": user.firstName,
                                        "lastName": user.lastName,
                                        "email": "Johnsmith@test11.com",
                                        "password": "12345678",
                                        "region": "EU",
                                        "bundleId":    Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!,
                                        "appVersion": Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as! String] 
    ...
    }

}
```

Comment: I am so close. My current issue is that My Viewcontroller has this, 

    let firstNameReg = inputFirstName.text
    let lastNameReg = inputLastName.text
    let newuser = NewUser(firstName: firstNameReg!, lastName: lastNameReg!)
    print(newuser)
    print(NewUser.self)

It prints the newuser fine but the NewUser is nil. When the code runs in the receiving VC it hits the guard "User is not set" as its nil? Confused face. (had to rename to NewUser as were using User in the baseviewcontroller!)

Comment: It sounds like you aren't assigning the property in the destination view controller. Is your prepare for segue code running?

Comment: it doesnt like         destVC.newuser = NewUser
gives error "cannot assign value of type baseviewcontroller.NewUser.Type to type baseviewcontroller.NewUser? "

Comment: you want `newUser` not `NewUser` - This is why it is important to stick to the convention of lower case letters for variables and upper case for classes/structs - it help avoids this sort of error.

Comment: the NewUser is the struct. I added new to the front of all user and New tot he front of all User. I buggered it up somewhere!

Comment: Yes, but you don't want to say `destVC.newUser = NewUser` you want `destVC.newUser = NewUser(firstName: firstNameReg!, lastName: lastNameReg!)` or just `destVC.newUser = newUser` if you have already created `newUser` as an instance of `NewUser`

Comment: let newuser = NewUserStruct(firstName: firstNameReg ?? "First Name Missing", lastName: lastNameReg ?? "Last Name Missing") is returning nil

Comment: Set a breakpoint in `prepare(for segue)` - Is it being called?  Is the destinationViewController property being set?

Comment: [link]http://imgur.com/a/LbrVT
 
its jumping right over the break point?

Comment: You have put your `prepare(for segue)` function inside `navbarViewNextPressed` function  - it should be outside of any other function but in your class

Comment: I have everything inside that function as it executes on the segue move. Is that the problem? Should I add a button and run the code on the IBAction?

Comment: The prepare for segue function is inherited from UIViewController. You can't put it inside another function scope; it won't be found, as you see. The performSegue is in the right place

Comment: Notice that my function as the `override` keyword and yours doesn't. In fact if you added it to yours, where it is now, you would get an error because it isn't overriding a superclass function. If my code didn't have that it would be an error because it is overriding the superclass function. If you don't override the superclass function then it won't be called